# ALTER TABLE LIKE

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use the LIKE statement on ALTER TABLE similar to CREATE TABLE in MySQL?

Eg.  'CREATE TABLE db.tbl1 LIKE db.tbl2'

This clones a database table's structure.  I want to alter an existing table with the same columns but to pick up the primary keys of another table.

I was thinking of something like 'ALTER TABLE db.tbl1 LIKE db.tbl2' but this throws back an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you know the columns that form the primary key, you can simply do the ALTER TABLE on the concerned table. Why bother about "like"?

Comment: `LIKE` is a comparison operator. Not a function to copy structure.

Comment: I have about 100 database with similar structure.  There was a script to clone the databases but it has a bug and it has not copied the primary keys.  Each database has about 80 tables without primary keys which isn't good.  There is the default database with the correct schema still so I was hoping to use that to update the other databases.

Answer (score 2):

I required a similar thing and settled to use the following procedure:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 RENAME tbl1_old;
CREATE TABLE tbl1 LIKE tbl2;
INSERT INTO tbl1 SELECT * FROM tbl1_old;
DROP TABLE tbl1_old;
```

Altough this is not a single statement it should do the job. Only problem could be different index settings (UNIQUE, etc.) which cause errors when doing the "INSERT INTO" of the original table contents.

Comment: Ok. Just noticed that you will have to specify fields for the "INSERT INTO" statement. This makes it somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: To ease things: You can use a query like the following to get a list of all columns of a table ready for copy&paste. So you can use the result of this query for automatically updating a large number of tables: select GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) from information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME='tbl1_old' group by TABLE_NAME order by ORDINAL_POSITION;

Answer (score 1):

Everything ALTER TABLE can do is explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

As you can see importing indexes from another table is not mentioned. You could probably do that with some clever `information_schema` querying, but I don't think it would be worth the cost.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [you can't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).