# Updating a table structure based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I have a table `tblA` which is based off the structure(columns) of `tblA_master` but over time the structure of `tblA_master` has changed but `tblA` has not followed these changes.

Is it possible to alter `tblA` based off the current strucutre of `tblA_master` and how can I do it.

Comment: Too few information to answer. What are the changes exactly? When data is the same, why on earth do you even have 2 tables?

Comment: Data in `tblA` are older records from `tblA_master`

Comment: you may refer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874474/alter-table-like)

Comment: I added a possible solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874474/alter-table-like

Answer (score 0):

If you need data as well do the following.

```
CREATE TABLE tblA [AS] SELECT * FROM tblA_master ;
```

Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) for details

If you need to create structure only follow the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE tblA LIKE tblA_master ;
```

Comment: Thats fine if I was creating a new table but as I mentioned in my original query `tblA` already exists, I was to update the structure.

Comment: so you need to have different data in tblA  from tblA_master ?

Comment: No the data is the same but the structure differs between the tables because of updates being missed. I wanted to bring the structure inline with the `master` table

Comment: Then drop the tblA first, then create using first query.

Comment: @fir3x: you can't alter one table from another table like in case of create. You have to drop and then create it again. you may backup the data, if you need it in future.

Comment: @NiteshMishra If you have no clue, it's better to say nothing at all.

Comment: @fir3x Not necessarily true what Nitesh Mishra said.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question